# Can't seem to figure out how to encrypt Kali Linux post-installation

Tags: linux, hard-drive, backup, kali-linux, disk-encryption

So I've been trying for the past few days now to encrypt my Kali install with LUKS. I've mostly been switching through different Linux distros to see what might be a good fit. I didn't choose to encrypt my installation when I installed because I didn't think I would be with Kali for very long. However, I found that I enjoy using Kali and I like the feel of it, so I decided I'd like to encrypt it. I can't however seem to figure out how without doing a fresh install of Kali, and I'd rather not do that. I've installed many programs and I have a bunch of data saved that I would not like to lose with a fresh install. I've seen a bunch of things about using ecrypt-fs to encrypt, but I believe that's only to encrypt the home folder, not the whole disk. Kali is currently the only operating system on my drive. I've heard that I could use cryptsetup, but that would mean I would have to backup my data before going through that process.

So, my question is, how do I LUKS encrypt my drive with Kali without losing my data? And if I need to backup, how do I go about that, as well as restoring my data when the time comes for me to do that? I have no external hard drive or server to backup to, that I know of. I would like to have encryption just like if I had encrypted it with my install.
Thanks in advance.

Sincerely, 
Me

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know,it can't be done.
first kali linux needs to be installed onto a flash drive (at least a 4gb) or dvd.
Then you do a graphical install from the flash/dvd drive, selecting encrypted LVM install.But you will need another disk with windows installed to install kali onto the flash drive or dvd. check here   https://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install
i hope this helps :)